# What radio antenna connector is required? (FM/AM)

Tags: connectors

I need to hook up a coaxial antenna cable from my FM antenna to my stereo. The stereo is actually an RV (recreational vehicle) unit because it fit into a very tight space in my house (wall mounted, limited depth) so maybe has a different connector than what you'd normally find.

The cable right now is just a bare coax cable that I need to add ends to. The antenna end is a normal male coax connector, but what the stereo end needs is unclear...

The manual doesn't say anything in detail about what type of connector is needed for the antenna cable. This is the diagram from [the manual](https://www.asaelectronics.com/downloads/dl/file/id/855/jwm6a_installation_and_operation_manual.pdf):

[image]

It literally says nothing at all about the connector.

This is a photo of the actual connector on the stereo:

[image]

(sorry that's not as clear as I'd like, its hard to get the camera in there without disassembling things).

I assume this is some kind of standard connector, but I'm not familiar with this type of thing to know any details. Its a Jensen stereo.

Comment: Based on the informative answers below i found this adapter to go from the **Motorola to coaxial F connector**.  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0756LMJQB/?coliid=I6EI9N5Y9OHX6&colid=43BDRCDIWC9Q&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it

Comment: @AlaskaMan thank you - I hadn't been able to find anything like that. That would be pretty much perfect for what I'm doing!

Comment: Downvote? No comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That connector will accept the coax type connector typically found on the end of an automotive type antenna cable. One will look like this:

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.joom.com/en/products/5b28be7d8b451301afb07106)*</sup>

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the tip will fit into the inner hole, while the larger outer part fits into the outer hole?

Comment: Also, do you know if there is a standard name / technical name for this type of connector? I take it from the link that this is the "DIN" style but I don't think that term uniquely identifies this exact style.

Comment: I have always known them as "car radio antenna connectors". Been in use for a long time (50 years or more). I have not seen a source for a DIY end kit for coax cable for many years.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs - You may want to see what you can find at a better auto parts store.  If you are an Amazon shopper this looks like what you need: https://www.amazon.com/Metra-40-UV40-Standard-Male-Antenna/dp/B0007WW66C/ref=sr_1_11?keywords=car+radio+antenna+connector&qid=1583688542&s=electronics&sr=1-11

Comment: Since the OP mentioned that it's in a tight space, he might find a [right angle car radio antenna adapter](https://www.amazon.com/Metra-44-EC6R-Universal-Antenna-Extension/dp/B0007WTELW) to be useful.

Answer (score 6):

This is a "Motorola" type connector. These have been around in automotive radios since nearly the beginning of auto radios which were introduced by Motorola. Motorola is basically gone but their connector lives on. I've also heard them called "auto antenna" connectors.

I'm sure there are some different ones on the market but this style is by far the most common.

According to Wikipedia they are also called DIN41585:

[Motorola Connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_connector)